# when modCount is initialized in java.util.ArrayList?

Tags: java, iterator

I want to know when the field modCount of java.util.ArrayList is initialized.From the source code of java.util.ArrayList,we know the field modCount is inherited from
java.util.AbstractList. And in the private inner class of java.util.ArrayList named  Itr,its field expectedModCount is assigned from modCout，as shown below

[image]

In a demo,I debugged and found that itr.expectedModCount has been initialized.Because the value of expectedModCount is from modCount.So I looked up the source code to find when modCount is initialized,but failed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is initialized to 0 (note that it's an instance variable of the `AbstractList` super-class):

```
protected transient int modCount = 0;
```

and incremented in several places in which the `List` is structurally modified (i.e. elements are added or removed).

For example:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    ....
}
```

Note that the `Itr` class is an inner class of `ArrayList`, and therefore it has access to the members of the enclosing `ArrayList` instance (which includes the `modCount` instance variable of the `AbstractList` super-class).

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I still have a doubt  when I debugged,I found taht the expectedModCount instance varaible of the Itr class did not equal to the value of modCount instance variable of the ArrayList.Because, in the source coe,filed expectedModCount of Itr given the value of modCount.They should be equal ，in theory

Comment: @ZhiZheng they are equal when the iterator is created. If you perform structural modifications on the `ArrayList` while iterating over it (not including calling `Iterator`'s remove method, which is allowed), the `modCount` be be incremented and will no longer be equal to the `Iterator`'s `expectedModCount`. That's how the `Iterator` knows you did something wrong, which allows it to fail fast (by throwing ConcurrentModificationException).

Comment: Thank you very much,I think you are right.I will study it carefully again

Answer (score 0):

When I lookup where `modCount` is located I can find it, it's located inside `java.util.AbstractList` and is declared as:

```
protected transient int modCount = 0;
```

This means that it's initialized when it's declared.